# Which pre-trained model works best for disaster classification

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, training-data, transfer-learning

I'm new to deep learning, I want to build a model that predicts the type of disaster (flood, Fire, Infrastructure damage) from a giving picture.
I want to proceed with transfer learning and I'm not sure which model would give me the best result.

I tried using building a cnn model from scratch but the I got a test accuracy = 70% which is low.

model code is below :

```
num_classes=3
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3),
             activation='relu',
             input_shape=(512,512,3)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
          optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

kf=KFold(n_splits=10 ,shuffle=True)

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
   print("Folding")
   x_train, x_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
   y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

   y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
   y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

   model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
   score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
   print('Test loss:', score[0])
   loss.append(score[0])
   print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
   acc.append(score[1])
```

PS : X is a numpy array with shape (3000,512,512,3) and Y is a numpy array with shape (3000,1) with values {0,1,2} for each class

Comment: CNN is a good choice but there are many parameters you can tune to improve accuracy. How many classes of disaster types do you have and how many images are in each class?

Comment: Parameters like what ? as a start, I have 3 classes and each class has nearly 1000 images. the thing is when I train my model using only two classes (Flood, Fire), I get an accuracy of 90% but when I add a third class which is Infrastructure damage I get below 70%

Comment: Considering the number of images and classes, 70% might actually be a decent result so far, but do more testing by changing values of parameters like dense layers, layer sizes, the number of convolution layers, image size, Dropout, batch size, epochs etc. Could you edit your question and add some of your code to see what parameters you are using.

Comment: Done. I added the model code to my question

Comment: Do some more testing by using different kernel_size=(9, 9), pool_size=(7, 7). Your code is not showing what values are used for batch_size=batch_size and epochs=epochs but you should also experiment with a different range of values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used transfer learning with resnet18 model with only 100 images in each of the three class resulting in accuracy of 99%.I think it should solve your problem.

Comment: can you please post your code ? and the dataset used if possible ! thank you.

Comment: actually i prefer pytorch.And if you want you can see the similar code at  : https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html  from where you can simply learn how to apply on your dataset